# Constructor function for Elm's extensible records / Json.Decoding of object hierarchies

Tags: elm

Let's say I have the following sort of type definitions:

```
type alias EntityBase =
    { id: Int
    , name : String
    }


-- Derived types

type alias PersonSpecfic entityBase =
    { entityBase 
        | age: Int
        , address : String
    }
type alias Person = PersonSpecfic EntityBase
```

**Are there any constructor functions for the types `Person / PersonSpecfic` in the current version of Elm (0.16)?**

*(the compiler says ``` "Cannot find variable ``PersonSpecfic``" ```)*

This is relevant to be able to create Json decoders for the type hierarchy.

Comment: The code you posted seems to work fine for me: http://share-elm.com/sprout/56df2267e4b070fd20daa505 (share-elm is only Elm 0.15, but I tested the same code locally with 0.16)

Comment: @robertjlooby the code I posted only includes the type definitions. Normally the name of the type also serves as a constructor function, but not in case "generic"/"extended" record definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Since elm 0.16, record extension does not exist in the language anymore.

Partially as a side effect of that, there are no constructor functions for record types defined in "generic"/"extended" fashion.

More details can be found on this thread: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elm-discuss/constructor/elm-discuss/AaL8iLjhEdU/JSAXV2oACgAJ

Answer (score 0):

Yea, that looks like a compiler bug. You could always create your own constructor function to use in JSON decoding:

```elm
createPerson : Int -> String -> Int -> String -> Person
createPerson id name age address =
  { id = id
  , name = name
  , age = age
  , address = address
  }
```